# Scala groupBy + mapValues vs. groupBy + map + breakOut

Tags: scala

Let's say I have data like this:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val data: List[Foo] = Foo(1,10) :: Foo(2, 20) :: Foo(3,30) :: Nil
data: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,10), Foo(2,20), Foo(3,30))
```

I know that in my data, there will be no instances of Foo with the same value of field `a` - and I want to transform it to `Map[Int, Foo]` (I don't want `Map[Int, List[Foo]]`)

I can either:

```
 scala> val m: Map[Int,Foo] = data.groupBy(_.a).mapValues(_.head)
 m: Map[Int,Foo] = Map(2 -> Foo(2,20), 1 -> Foo(1,10), 3 -> Foo(3,30))
```

or:

```
scala> val m: Map[Int,Foo] = data.groupBy(_.a).map(e => e._1 -> e._2.head)(collection.breakOut)
m: Map[Int,Foo] = Map(2 -> Foo(2,20), 1 -> Foo(1,10), 3 -> Foo(3,30))
```

My questions:

1) How could I make the implementation with `breakOut` more concise / idiomatic?

2) What should I be aware of "under the covers" in each of the above-two solutions? I.e. hidden memory / compute costs.  In particular, I am looking for a "layperson's" explanation of `breakOut` that does not necessarily involve an in-depth discussion of the signature of `map`.

3) Are there any other solutions I should be aware of (including, for example, using libraries such as ScalaZ)?

Comment: Why do you even use `groupBy` in this case? You could just do `data.map{case x@Foo(a,_) => a -> x}.toMap`, if you assume that there are no duplicate `a`'s.

Comment: Because I'm working with legacy code that uses groupBy all over the place. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about `breakOut`.  That's super handy.

Answer (score 6):

1) As pointed out by @Kigyo, the right answer, given that there are no duplicate `a`s, wouldn't use `groupBy`:

```
val m: Map[Int,Foo] = data.map(e => e.a -> e)(breakOut)
```

Using `groupBy` is good when there could be duplicate `a`s, but is totally unnecessary given your problem.

2) First, don't use `mapValues` if you plan on accessing values multiple times.  The `.mapValues` method does not create a new Map (like the `.map` method does).  Instead, it creates a *view* of a Map that recomputes the function (`_.head` in your case) every time it is accessed.  If you plan on accessing things a lot, consider `map{case (a,b) => a -> ??}` instead.

Second, passing the `breakOut` function as the `CanBuildFrom` parameter does not incur additional costs. The reason for this is that the `CanBuildFrom` parameter is *always* present, just sometimes it's implicit.  The true signature is this:

```
def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

The purpose of the `CanBuildFrom` is to tell scala how to make a `That` out of the result of mapping (which is a collection of `B`s).  If you leave off `breakOut`, then it uses an implicit `CanBuildFrom`, but either way, there must be a `CanBuildFrom` so that there is some object that is able to build the `That` out of the `B`s.

Finally, in your example with `breakOut`, the `breakOut` is completely redundant since `groupBy` produces a `Map`, so `.map` on a `Map` gives you back a `Map` by default.

```
val m: Map[Int,Foo] = data.groupBy(_.a).map(e => e._1 -> e._2.head)
```